# Azure Sentinel, where are changes logged for data connectors

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel

Does anyone know what to query to find who may have made changes to the Azure Sentinel / Data Connector Configuration?

I tried the activity log but couldn't quite find the change; experimenting in my dev making changes but ultimately i'm trying to track down who made changes in PROD.

Thanks in advance,

Boyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following?

https://github.com/rod-trent/SentinelKQL/blob/master/UpdateDataConnectors.txt

AzureActivity
| where OperationName == "Update Data Connectors" and ActivityStatus == "Succeeded"
| project Caller , CallerIpAddress, EventSubmissionTimestamp